# Can I configure WordPress to use postfix without a plugin?

Tags: email, wp-config, wp-mail, configuration

I am developing a WordPress site on a vagrant box and have installed postfix in order to test email notifications.

At this guest OS (Ubuntu) level, I am able to end a test email:

```
echo "Test mail from postfix" | mail -s "Test Postfix" my@email.address
```

This works and I receive the email. As far as I know postfix uses the sendmail binary and so I would expect WordPress to send emails successfully.

However, my contact form notifications are not being received. Is there a way to check/debug email sending in WordPress or verify which mail function it is using?

**UPDATE**

So after a bit of digging I discovered that `wp_mail()` uses PHPMailer. If I debug the `wp_mail()` function using this test script I see that PHPMailer is throwing an exception:

> Could not instantiate mail function.

```
// Set $to as the email you want to send the test to
$to = "myreal@email.address.com";

// No need to make changes below this line

// Email subject and body text
$subject = 'wp_mail function test';
$message = 'This is a test of the wp_mail function: wp_mail is working';
$headers[] = 'From: Me Myself <myreal@email.address.com>';

// Load WP components, no themes
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp/wp-load.php');

// Call the wp_mail function, display message based on the result.
if( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
    // the message was sent...
    echo 'The test message was sent. Check your email inbox.';
} else {
    // the message was not sent...
    echo 'The message was not sent!';
};
```

Comment: What is the output of `ini_get( 'sendmail_path' );`? By default it should be pointing to a local sendmail binary/link, for example `/usr/sbin/sendmail`. Make sure it exists and is pointing to your Postfix binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress uses the [wp_mail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) function to send mail. It says on the Codex article there that:

> For this function to work, the settings SMTP and smtp_port (default: 25) need to be set in your php.ini file.

Also be sure to check that your contact form is sending the required parameters to the wp_mail() function. The required parameters are included on the page in the link above.

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to be the case. However, on this particular setup, I have postfix installed and the SMTP information in stored in the postfix config. I can't seem to find any decent information on how to configure PHP to use that config,

Comment: I am having a similar issue please see http://serverfault.com/questions/803491/wordpress-nginx-postfix-uncaught-exception-phpmailerexception